# Express.js know where link to page was clicked

Tags: express

Where in the req object can I see where I came from in Express.js.

Say I have the same navbar on every page of my site, but I click on a link in that navbar.  Under certain conditions, I want to redirect to the calling page instead of going to the clicked link.  In the middle where for those routes I should be able to find what page I clicked on the link at in the request object, am I right?

Comment: So you basically want to redirect a user back to page which they came from?

Answer (score 0):

[Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) is what are you looking for. Inside your controller, If you  `console.log(req.headers)` you will see a property `referer` containing the address of the previous web page.
So, in case you want to redirect back you can use this `res.redirect(req.headers.referer);`